# Como pegar elemento acima Jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

Tenho os seguintes elementos:

```
<p class="id-task">5</p>
<p class="status-change">
    <i id="test-task" class="fa fa-flask fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
</p>
```

Estou tentando pegar o numero 5 dento de `<p class="id-task">5</p>` com o seguinte código Jquery:

```
$('#test-task').on('click', function(){ 
    var father = $(this).parent().siblings();
    var idTask = $(father).text();
    alert(idTask);  
});
```

Eu alterei o código, porque o `parent()` final tem que ser `.siblings()`, porque o `<p class="id-task">5</p>` é irmão de `<p class="status-change"></p>`

Answer (score 4):

o método prev() devolve o elemento anterior.

```
$('#test-task').on('click', function(){ 
    var element = $(this).parent().prev();
    var idTask = $(element).text();
    alert(idTask);  
});
```

Comment: Eu usaria algo como 
var id = $(this).parent().parent().find('id-task').text();

Comment: pode haver vários elementos com a classe "id-task".

Answer (score 3):

Mude para  `$(father).text();`, você tá pegando o html todo.

```
$('#test-task').on('click', function(){ 
    var father = $(this).parent().parent();
    var idTask = $(father).text();
    alert(idTask);  
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Só pegar pela classe.

```
$('.id-task').text();
```

### JS

```
$('#test-task').on('click', function(){ 
    var idTask = $('.id-task').text();
    alert(idTask);  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Utilize a função [`.prev()`](https://api.jquery.com/prev/)

`.prev()` traz sempre o elemento anterior

No caso seu evento click chama um elemento dentro de um paragrafo se vc quer um acima de onde ele está. Faça assim:

```
$('#test-task').on('click', function(){ 
    var idTask = $(this).parent().prev().text();
    alert(idTask);  
});
```